# ' What application' for downlaod

Tags: sound, downloads

I'm trying desperatly hard to play an audio recording I made on my S4. I have transfered it but I can't play it. When I try and download VLS it keeps asking ' What application?' Can anyone please advise. I have a deadline!

Mark

Comment: What does VLS means ?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you mean VLC instead of VLS, you can find this app in the Ubuntu Software Center, just type in dash "Ubuntu software center" without the quotes and when it starts, just locate VLC media player through the search bar and you are done.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Anyway, for further responses, we must know the file extension :P.